# Forecasted temperature in the shade vs. theoretical temperature in the sun

Tags: temperature, weather, meteorology

I understand that different objects absorb different amounts of light (blackbody absorption). I wonder how feasible it would be to calculate the approximate temperature in the sun based upon the forecasted temperature (shade) — essentially a "feels like" in the sun. It's always some number of degrees warmer... it would be nice to quantify that. Does that depend on the absorption of a given person's skin (and thus vary depending upon their skin tone)? If so, would it be possible to calibrate an equation that predicts feels like temp in the sun by various lighter and darker skin tones? (see the [Fitzpatrick scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzpatrick_scale) for reference)

Comment: I think this is a question appropriate for earth science SE. https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would you mind linking your question from the earth science SE if you happen to ask there?

Comment: sure, here it is: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/24775/forecasted-temperature-in-the-shade-vs-theoretical-feels-like-temperature-in